# How can I get first record from joined table in foreign table with Symfony query builder?

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony1

I have two tables namely Article and Version.

The article table can have many versions.

```
Aritcle:
ID | title
1  | title 1
2  | title 2

Version
ID | title     | aritcle_id | date_create
1  | version 1 | 1          | 2015-10-09 12:32:23
2  | version 2 | 1          | 2015-10-08 9:10:20
3  | version 3 | 1          | 2015-10-08 8:10:20
4  | version 4 | 2          | 2015-10-08 10:10:20
```

I am standing in Version, then I want to get only first created version which is joined with article.

The expected result should be like this:

```
ID  | title
3   | version 3
4   | version 4
```

How can I write query to get the result as above?

Comment: which version of the framework do you refer? sf1+doctrine1 or sf2+docrine2? I don't remember the querybuilder of the version1 of the frameworks... let me know

Comment: I am using symfony2+doctrine2

Comment: ok, the date_Create field is not the date which the version is created? From the sample data seems not.... only by id we can find the first created version?

Comment: Oh my fault, I added simple data with mistake, it should be the first ID is the first creation.

Answer (score 0):

For `Article_id = 1` first created version is `version 3` because it was created earlier.

```
    select V.ID,V.title
        from Version V
        join (   select article_id,MIN(date_create) as date_create 
                 from Version 
                 group by article_id) as MINDATE
              on V.article_id = MINDATE.article_id 
              and V.date_create = MINDATE.date_create
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed tag Symfony. This answer is correct for sqlserver

Comment: That's ok @Andrey Davydenko, I will try my best to convert it to Symfony